# AuthzPolicy permissions for specific tickets in trac

Tags: trac

I'm using the AuthzPolicy-plugin to manage the permissions in a trac-env. Now I like to set a permission that disallow all users except for the admins to view tickets with a specific status.

I try a lot such as the following entry in the authzpolicy.conf:

```
[ticket:*/status:new]
@administrators = TICKET_VIEW
* =
```

Does the AuthzPolicy-plugin provides permission-setting for tickets with a specific status, owner or something else?

mutetella

Answer (score 0):

Trac's permissions system is focused on the component level.  You can turn on or off access to an entire component, but not to sub-content inside of that component.

That being said, you can create a plugin that emulates a more fine-grained permissions system.  The plugin would need to implement `IRequestFilter` and inspect the URL of pages when they load.  It would extract the ticket number from the URL, look up the ticket details in the database, and determine if the current user should view that page.  If the user doesn't have permission, the plugin would re-direct the request to an error page.  This is not too incredibly difficult to do (I've done it before to guard a specific wiki page), but it's hard to maintain because it's a separate permissions mechanism that's completely independent of Trac's permissions system.

Comment: Disagree, because Trac wiki documentation has http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions for configuration at resource level. That's what the OP already mentioned anyway, right?

Comment: @hasienda- You are correct.  I wasn't considering that feature since it doesn't work well on tickets, and I should have explicitly mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[TracFineGrainedPermissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions) can use any property represented in the resource path.

Revisions do, so you'll find an example explained as "John has BROWSER_VIEW and FILE_VIEW access to only revision 1 of 'somefile' at trunk/src/some/location only"

So the direct answer to your question is No, you can't do the same depending on ticket status, because all tickets look the same from the resource URL regardless of their status, sorry.

I agree, that you can resort to implementing a custom policy as already outlined by bta as a last resort.